# TransferFromLocal to hadoop hdfs using many threads

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to transfer lots of files from local to hadoop hdfs.
In my java code, I just have one connection to hadoop. But I call

```
 fileSystem.transferFromLocal
```

simultaneous in 50 threads.

I think this might be not a good way,because it's really slow.

Could anyone please give me some suggestion about this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out the bottle neck causing the slow transfer, it could be any. Just increasing the number of threads won't increase the HDFS writes proportionally. Without getting into details about your Hadoop cluster, it's difficult to diagnose the problem.

Here are some of the things to consider

1. Check the network band width between the local machine and the Hadoop cluster.
2. Local disk i/o could also be the bottle neck.
3. Try increasing the number of data nodes. Note that the data is directly streamed from the client to the first data node in the pipe line. The first forwards to the second, which forwards to the next data node.
4. Check any configuration parameters to fine tune HDFS.

Check the [Architecture Guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/hdfs_design.html) for more details about HDFS.